# How to configure the graphql endpoint in Netflix DGS with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, graphql, netflix-dgs

I have a simple hello world example using Netflix DGS (8.2.2) and Spring Boot (3.2.1), by default the graphql endpoint is exposed on /graphql endpoint

I tried to change the graphql endpoint to /gql by adding configurations in the application.yml

```
dgs:
  graphql:
    endpoint: /gql
```

Its not working. I am still able to access the application on /graphql only
Any idea what is wrong ?